# Bash get value of loop var

Tags: bash, loops

I want to create files Foo{A..Z} and insert "This is file [A-Z]" in the files.

Example:
FooG should contain the text
`This is file G`

First I need to create the files:
`touch foo{A..Z}`

Then I need to insert the text i want into all files:
`echo This is file{A..Z} > foo{A..Z}`

This won't quite work, as I need the *current* loop variable value
(which is somewhere between A and Z) from the `foo{A..Z}` from the line above.

Answer (score 5):

No need to create the files first, just use a loop:

```
for i in {A..Z}; do
    echo "This is file $i" > "Foo$i"
done
```

Now `$i` can be used to refer to the letter to be inserted, as well as part of the filename.